# How to align checkboxes

Tags: css

This is the code I have. I want the two checkboxes to be on top of each other but also to be aligned. Currently, when the code is run, the checkboxes appear all the way at the left of the screen and also don't seem to want to center even when I use justify-content: center.

Please help and thank-you!

```
  <input name="change" type="checkbox" value="Borrow Time">Borrow Time</label>
  <label><input name="change" type="checkbox" value="No Cigs">No Cigs </label>

label{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 180px;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, first, have you read the following? [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are expecting ?

```css
.flex-container {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
}
.inner-flex-container {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
<div class="inner-flex-container">
<label>
  <input name="change" type="checkbox" value="Borrow Time">Borrow Time</label>
<label>
  <input name="change" type="checkbox" value="No Cigs">No Cigs
</label>
</div>
</div>
```

> Explanation

`justify-content: center;` only works with flex box, you have to use `display: flex` on same element to work `justify-content: center;`

If you have observe the above example, I have wrapped the `label` and `checkbox` in 2 `div`'s because one is to center horizontally and other is to be on top of each other.

I can do this with one div, but if your content/child is not same in length then it look like example below

```css
.flex-container {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
<label>
  <input name="change" type="checkbox" value="Borrow Time">Borrow Time</label>
<label>
  <input name="change" type="checkbox" value="No Cigs">No Cigs
</label>
</div>
```

> **Note:** if you use `flex-direction: column` the `align-items` is used to center horizontally instead of `justify-content` because you changed the default direction `row` to `column` More details [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Use as below code snippet:

```
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}
label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 123px;
}

<div class="flex-container">
   <label>
   <input 
          name="change"
          type="checkbox"
          value="Borrow Time">Borrow Time</label>
  <label>
    <input 
           name="change"
           type="checkbox"
           value="No Cigs">No Cigs 
  </label>
  </div>
```